# subset a-rules in R by length of lhs

Tags: r, data-mining, arules

I'm using the `arules` package in `R` to extract some association rules and want to filter by the length of the left hand side (lhs).

I tried using subset but without success.

This is my mode and attempt:

```
  trans<-read.transactions(file='file.csv', format="single", sep=",",cols=c("userid","target"))

  inspect(head(trans,3))

  rules<-apriori(trans,parameter=list(support=0.06, confidence=0.5,minlen=3,maxlen=6)) 

  # sort by support
  top.support <- sort(rules, decreasing = TRUE, na.last = NA, by = "support")
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
subset(rules,subset=length(lhs)==5) # not working. it return set of 0 rules
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`length` gives you the number of rules. You need to use `size` instead.

`subset(rules,subset = size(lhs) == 5)`